# Query Output Window not honoring fixed length

Tags: sql-server-2000

Query below has fixed length values for data set being returned in a string, now the problem is that fixed lengths are not being honored in the query results. But the output text file produced by DB mail looks correct. See examples below:

```
     SELECT 
          LEFT(CONVERT(char(9), machine) + SPACE(9),9) 
          + LEFT(CONVERT(char(30), part_no) + SPACE(30), 30) 
          + LEFT(CONVERT(char(7), ordered) + SPACE(7), 7) 
          + LEFT(CONVERT(char(7), picked)  + SPACE(7), 7) 
          + LEFT(CONVERT(char(7), allocated)  + SPACE(7), 7)
          + LEFT(CONVERT(char(7), in_stock)  + SPACE(7), 7) 
          + LEFT(CONVERT(char(7), sh_bin_qty)  + SPACE(7), 7)  
          + LEFT(CONVERT(char(7), short)  + SPACE(7), 7) 
          + min_bin
```

Raw Output Results

[image: image1]

Text File Results

[image: image1]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is honoring the fixed character length.  However, it does not appear to be using a monospaced font so it looks like it isn't.  The character length is fixed for the column.  The character width is font dependent.  DB Mail is using a monospaced font.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font

> A monospaced font, also called a fixed-pitch, fixed-width, or
>   non-proportional font, is a font whose letters and characters each
>   occupy the same amount of horizontal space.[1] This contrasts with
>   variable-width fonts, where the letters and spacings have different
>   widths.

Notice that the space taken up by an `M` is more than taken up by an `I`

Comment: If I want to send the results in an email body instead of an attachment would I have to use an HTML table to have the correct format? If I set @attach_query_result_as_file = 0 i receive the non monospace output.

Comment: As long as the recipient isn't limited to plain text emails that would work.  You could also attach the data as a spreadsheet.